# Start data downloading in background mode

Tags: iphone, xcode, background

I need to have the following things to work while my iphone  application is in the background mode.

1.Run a clock.

2.Communicate with the server every 15 mins to get the server time and one another value.

3.Need to start downloading data in background mode.

I searched a lot whether these are possible or not. Kindly give confirmation on these.

I am developing an iPhone application which involves Ticket Booking System. I registered my application as location based beacuse it is using user's location taken in background for a purpose.

My problem is that i need to run an internal clock in my application in background mode. I need to write the codes for internal clock in core location delegate methods, so that internal clock will also run along with the location bsed services. Will my app get rejected? Is anything wrong in doing like this?

I need to get the correct time to use in my app, so that i am running this internal clock. I can use NSDate, but that will return the device time. Anyone can change the device time. So once somebody chaged, wrong time will affect the smooth functioning of the app. Kindly some body suggest to get the correct time with out running the internal clock ?

Comment: And what did your searches discover?

Comment: You cannot do this while your app is in background mode.

Comment: My application is highly depended on the above things..Kindly suggest some solutions. In my research i found that background services is permitted only for location based apps, VOIP and music playing. And also continue a finite length process in background, that too for about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to do this with your app not running in the foreground - and that is not possible, if you don't use some tricks like playing an empty audio file and pretending to be a music player or the like.

**In iOS, you can only execute code of your app while it is actively running in the foreground**, except for some specific tasks like VOIP or music playing.

If you want to do this while your app is running in the foreground, just use *NSTimer* and a background process for loading, like it was suggested. But then you should also prevent the iPhone from entering SLEEP mode after 1 minute, otherwise it won't work when th euser is not actively using the app during the 15 minutes ...

Comment: Yes, i want to do all these ,  when the application is not running in the foreground. I need to call webservice every 15 mins and trigger downloading by checking the response getting from API. In the apple documentation  i saw background services is permitted only for location based apps, VOIP and music playing.Is there any way to do my requirements.Please explain the tricks in detail.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not do any of this up to now, and I suppose Apple is also frowning on anyone using the background running processes for anything else than intended - your app might be rejected. If you really want to do it, google around, there's lots of explanation on how to use the tricks.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, what you need to do is,

1] Run a background thread, in which set a NSTimer with 15mins.

2] Set repeat:YES to call it at every 15mins.

3] And start download your need there!

I will do like this if I stuck like your situation!

Comment: I want to execute all while app is not running in foreground.Is the method suggested by you is possible in my case? Kindly confirm.

Comment: You need to run some background thread in application delegate.